# Active Directory LDAP password change: insufficient access rights

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap, unboundid-ldap-sdk

I need to write a program that let's an authenticated user to change its password on Active Directory at Windows Server 2003 functional level.

By requirements of our security manager my program must use LDAP, but it can't bind with an administrator account nor a delegated account.

I need to bind to LDAP with credentials provided by the user and with that connection modify the password.

I'm using java with UnboundID. Code as follow:

```
LDAPConnection connection = new LDAPConnection(new SSLUtil(new TrustAllTrustManager()).createSSLSocketFactory("SSLv3"), "dc.mydomain.loc", 636);    
Modification modification = new Modification(ModificationType.REPLACE, "unicodePwd", ('"' + newPassword + '"').getBytes("UTF-16LE"));
connection.bind(userDN, oldPassword);
connection.modify(userDN, modification);
```

I'm sure userDN and oldPassword are correct as the bind operation terminates successfully. But when I run the modification I get the following error:

```
LDAPException(resultCode=50 (insufficient access rights), diagnosticMessage='00000005: SecErr: DSID-031A0F44, problem 4003 (INSUFF_ACCESS_RIGHTS), data 0', ldapSDKVersion=4.0.4, revision=27051)
at com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.LDAPConnection.modify(LDAPConnection.java:2881)
```

Comment: Not sure. Might want to verify as Microsoft requires a minimum level of LDAP encryption of 128 bit SSL. Check that password is not expired/Disabled? Change password as user within Microsoft Active Directory tools?